# How to use aggregation to count the docs AND sum up a specific field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get the count of leads that match a list ID and combine it with their cost. Here is my collection:

```
[
  {
    "list_id": "5f76a53e8a93be772c14cc06",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "cost": 0
  },
  {
    "list_id": "5f76a53e8a93be772c14cc06",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Wayne",
    "cost": 0.65
  },
  {
    "list_id": "5f76a53e8a93be772c14cc06",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Kelly",
    "cost": 1
  },
  {
    "list_id": "5f76a53e8a93be772c14cc06",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Morrie",
    "cost": 0.40
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "lead_count": 4
    "total_cost": 2.05
  }
]
```

My aggregation looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      list_id: "5f76a53e8a93be772c14cc06"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      total_cost: {
        $sum: "$cost"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But it only gives me:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "total_cost": 2.05
  }
]
```

How do I need to tweak it for it to yeild what I want? Here is the Playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zvLY67Oa_Ps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the new field you want to add, i.e. `lead_count`.

Only is necessary one object more: `"lead_count": { "$sum": 1 },` into `$group` stage.

The stage will be like this:

```js
"$group": {
  "_id": null,
  "lead_count": {
    "$sum": 1
  },
  "total_cost": {
    "$sum": "$cost"
  }
}
```

Note that in this way you are creating the new field and using `$sum : 1` to increment one for each value.
That means: You are creating the field `lead_count` where you store the count of the documents whose match the first stage.

Example query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RAQ5hTbzUhF)

Comment: This works. Added a `$project` to drop the `_id: null` and I'm good to go. Thank you.